# How to know the probability of an outcome due to a specific factor

Tags: probability, bayesian

Imagine I have a virus that cause a disease in the 60% of the cases (virus A), and another virus which cause it in the 30% of the cases (virus B).

How can I know the probability of virus B beeing responsible of a patient?

I have tried to solve this using Bayes theorem:

> `P(virus B / ill) = [P(ill / virus B) * P(virus B)] / P(ill)`

The problem is that I have no data regarding P(ill) so, how can I solve this?

Additionally: am I right if I assume P(virus B) as 0.3?

Comment: I'm not yet sure of the answer, but it might help if you were more careful in choosing terms.  Here are questions we don't know the answer to that matter: (1) presumably, P(ill/virus) = 1.0 for both A and B (both make people ill when they get it - making P(ill / virus B = 1.0); (2) Are the viruses mutually exclusive or do they overlap - in other words, do 90% of the people get sick on average and no one gets A and B together, or can people get both at the same time? A few of these need to be thought about, and putting a bit more thought into your equation  often helps when using Bayes Theorem.

Comment: This is actually simpler than you're making it out to be, depending on the problem.

If a patient can contract both viruses (so the probabilities are independent), then the probability of getting both is P(A)*P(B) = 0.18. 

Then the probability of B not A is still just 0.3. 

If contracting one virus changes the probability of contracting the other virus, then it's not so simple.

Comment: I don't have this information, all the information that I have is that both virus are independent (so I assume they can overlap or not).

Comment: If both viruses are independent, then the probability of virus B being responsible is just the probability of contracting virus B, 30%.

Comment: These comments by @TonyC appear to confuse the concept of statistical independence with the idea of having equal probabilities, but that's wrong.  If you don't have a prior probability distribution for contracting the viruses, then you simply haven't enough information to answer your question.  (The independence assumption is questionable, anyway, because people highly susceptible to one virus are likely to be highly susceptible to the other.)

Comment: @whuber, can you elaborate on why we can't assume random selection (or equal probabilities)? Wouldn't that depend on the problem? If I'm speaking about a hypothetical sample (as I inferred from the question), then I am assuming equal probabilities. If the problem is about who stumbles into a hospital emergency room, then we wouldn't have equal probabilities.. Agreed more information is needed.

Comment: @TonyC I may have misread the question, but it seems to me we are told that among otherwise healthy persons ("cases") exposed to virus A, 60% of them contract a disease and among persons exposed to virus B, 30% of them contract that disease.  Given someone is observed with that disease, what is the chance it was caused by by virus B?

Comment: If you have the knowledge that someone is infected only, you do not have enough information above to determine the probability they got it from one virus or the other, because you don't know the proportion of the population that have virus A and B.